# Transmit reversed url to include tag

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

I have created a template which I'll include in different other templates.

It contains something like this:

**ajax_create_object_inclusion.html**

```
<a class="custom-control" data-url="{{ creation_url }}" href="javascript:void(0)">Plus</a>
```

It is used like this:

**home.html**

```
{% url 'frames:create' as frame_create_url %}

{% include 'general/cbv/cbv_inclusions/create_object_inclusion.html' with creation_url=frame_create_url %}
```

I failed to use nested tags in templates.

Could you help me understand whether this is the most rational way? Or I somehow can change ajax_create_object_inclusion.html so that I could use only one include string instead of two tags (url and include).

Comment: What do you mean, two include strings?

Comment: Pardon for that. Edited the question. I mean that 'url' tag is a bit irrational here in my view.